# How to get vimeo thumbnail to have a parallax effect/fixed background (CSS)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vimeo, semantic-ui-react

I used react-semantic-ui and I used the Embed tag as shown:

```
import { Embed } from 'semantic-ui-react'

<Embed className='testFixed' aspectRatio="16:9" onClick={()=> console.log('clicked') } 
id='125292332' placeholder='./images/celeb0.png' source='vimeo' />
```

Now, I'm trying to get the thumbnail to be fixed.

So far I've tried background-attachment: fixed; which doesn't work.  position: fixed works however, it's not the same as background-attachment.

```
.testFixed, .testFixed:before  {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-attachment: fixed;    
    /*background-size: cover; */
    /*position: fixed !important;*/
}
```

I'm pretty lost here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a background-image that was set via CSS so background-attachment will not work...

Comment: @SakoBu That makes sense.  Do you know how to get the placeholder fixed?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code... There are possible workarounds but I've given you the direction in which to go... If you want the 'paralax' effect you need to figure how to set that image as a background-image via CSS...